# Hosting .NET Web Service on WebLogic

Tags: .net, web-services, weblogic

Is there any way we can host .NET (.asmx) web service on web logic?

Thanks
Paresh

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic is written in Java and is a product of Oracle.

There is very little chance of Oracle writing .NET support for Weblogic, as they see Microsoft as a competitor.

You will have to write you web services within weblogic with JavaEE.